# Multiple Form Actions to different pages / different target windows

Tags: forms, submit

I have a form on my page that needs to have multiple form actions associated with it. I'm using the following script in conjunction with the following code to achieve this:

```
<script>
    function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('summary').action = action;
        document.getElementById('summary').submit();
    }
</script>


<form action="go-gold.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="image" id="arrow" name="go_back" onclick="submitForm('go-gold.php')" value="go_back" src="images/arrow_back.png" class="submit_button" /><br>

<input type="image" id="arrow" name="submit_form" onclick="submitForm('registration.php')" value="submit_form" src="images/arrow.png" class="submit_button" />
</form>
```

The first button needs to "go back" within the same browser window (self), and the second button needs to submit the info to a new window (blank). How do I modify the code to achieve this? Putting "target" functions within the input type doesn't work, and putting the target in the Form tag makes both submit buttons submit to the same window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with jQuery, also you have to identical ids for two separate form elements. You should have these as distinct ids unless you want to use a class name. Php can submit forms to the same page using the $_SERVER superglobal by using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] as the forms action name.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".submit_button").click(function() {
            clickVal = $(".submit_button").val();
            if(clickVal == 'go_back') {
                //do go back stuff
            }

            if(clickVal == 'submit_form') {
                // do actions for other page
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <form action="go-gold.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
       <input type="image" value="go_back" src="images/arrow_back.png" class="submit_button" /><br>
       <input type="image" value="submit_form" src="images/arrow.png" class="submit_button" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand. Where's the part where, if I click on the Go Back button (arrow_back), the form submits to the same window (showing the go-gold.php page), or if I click on the submit button, (arrow.png), the form submits to a new window, showing the registration.php page?

Comment: These are the lines that are commented with the two forward slashes // you will need to replace these with relevant js for redirecting or loading the current page

Comment: That's the part I need help with. What is that code supposed to be?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this with js if you google('redirecting with javascript'). This link shows the code you will need. http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html